# How to send a value to exec's running code

Tags: python, exec

*First*, I have two classes like this:

```
class A(object):
    def foo(self, context):
        print(context)

class B(object):
    def foo(self, context):
        print(context)
```

Notice the `context` variable here.

*Second*, I want to call A and B in exec like this:

```
body = """
a = A()
a.foo()
b = B()
b.foo()
"""
exec(body)
```

I also have some other classes which use `context`.

Which means that I don't want the `context` variable appeared in the `body` code. It's been generated in other place. And I want to send it by exec or other methods.

So how can I do this?

Comment: Since the parameter `context` is not optional, `a.foo()` will always fail.

Comment: Yes, so how can I send the context to foo by exec, I can modify the foo method, this is not importent.

Comment: Do you have control over generation of body code?

Comment: No, the body code is written by user in web client.

Comment: The `context` is used to identify this body code.

Comment: The code which is generating your body code will need to add atleast some placeholder in line `a.foo()` so that you can add value to that when calling exec

Comment: Yes, or I can change the foo method, I can control this A class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `context` a global variable instead:

```
class A(object):
    def foo(self):
        print(context)

class B(object):
    def foo(self):
        print(context)

body = """
a = A()
a.foo()
b = B()
b.foo()
"""
context = 'foobar'
exec(body)
```

This outputs:

```
foobar
foobar
```

Comment: Thanks,Your answer maybe right,and I'll test it soon.But I have many places will use  this `context` variable,Not just in A,So dose it have some other methods ?

Comment: I don't add context in foo method's param, Because I think can the context be defined in other place?

Comment: I had test this, Which can't work, Told me that context is not defined, Because A and B not at the same place as exec.

Comment: Does your test code not look like this working demo? https://repl.it/@blhsing/ExcitableMessyNewsaggregator

Comment: More like this:https://repl.it/@shoufengwei/TechnicalBigApplicationsoftware

Comment: So the classes are defined in a different module. In that case you have to import the classes from that module and assign your external value to `context` as an attribute of the module object: https://repl.it/@blhsing/TechnicalBigApplicationsoftware

Comment: @blhsing why `object` in `class A(object)` ?  . Any study link...

Comment: @PIG `object` is the base class for all new-style classes. You can read about new vs. old-style classes here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/what-is-the-difference-between-old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python

Comment: if i am not using `object` inside class still it is giving same result.

Comment: @PIG For the purpose of this question it makes no difference. New-style classes have several features that are not available to old-style classes. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19950198/6890912) summarizes them well.